# Is my toilet operating properly

Tags: toilet

My toilet tank has the tube going to the overflow but the overflow doesn't go to the bowl so I assume it goes down the drain. Is this ok. the bowl still fills up at each flush.

Comment: Overflow tube carries water to the bowl there is no drain   Water only leaves the tank by way of the bowl.   During refill after a flush do you see water flowing into bowl?

Comment: No, Imediatley after flush the bowl fills up but not from around the rim or from the overflow, there is a hole at the front of the bowl and water comes out there. When I had  a problem with one toilet leaking  water continually after flushing I could hear it leaking and my pressure pump would stay on but nothing was going in the bowl so I can only assume it was bypassing the bowl and going directly down the sewer line

Answer (score 1):

The overflow tube empties into the bowl. When the bowl water level rises to  certain point, water starts going down the drain. You can verify this by pushing your float down in a full tank. You'll notice that the level in the tank rises but the level in the bowl rises too. You can see water entering the bowl usually from the rim. Water can only get to the drain by going into the bowl first.

(Picture from Home Tips)

[image]

Comment: I agree it is the only way to fill the bowl. The method may not be obvious as most fill from the rim yours uses a less expensive method of filling at the trap.